# Relationship between CollectionView.collectionViewLayout and collectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewlayout

Apples api shows that: collectionView.collectionViewLayout is a UICollectionViewLayout type and it inheritance from NSObject . if i code this it could work well

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.5;
```

from this codes i guess the type of the collectionViewLayout is：UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

but if i custom define  a layout that inheritance from UICollectionViewLayout like this:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[CustomCollectionViewLayout alloc]init];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.5;
```

it crash and show :

> -[CustomCollectionViewLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111d0b840

This result is antagonistic to my guess, anyone can explain this , great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`.

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has a property named `minimumLineSpacing` and UICollectionViewLayout don't have it.

Hence when you call

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.5;
```

On your layout which is `UICollectionViewLayout` app crashes.

Hope it helps

Comment: the result is that UICollectionViewLayout the property of  UICollectionView  is  UICollectionViewFlowLayout  type ,and it  inheritance UICollectionViewLayout

Comment: @小丑王 : Yes, but again u confused the name of the property with type :) lemme re-phrase : collectionViewLayout property of UICollectionView is of type UICollectionViewLayout. You can assign any custom subclass of type UICollectionViewLayout to collectionView instance :) Similarly apple has created a subclass called UICollectionViewFlowLayout which as you said inherits from UICollectionViewLayout :) Because its a subclass of UICollectionViewLayout you can set UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance to collectionView. collectionViewLayout property :)

Comment: and UICollectionViewFlowLayout class has a property named minimumLineSpacing and obviously its parent class which is UICollectionViewLayout does not have it :) In your case u created a instance of parent class (UICollectionViewLayout) and tried accessing the property defined in child class (UICollectionViewFlowLayout). Obviously compiler could not find that property hence crashed :) Hope it helps :)

Comment: your comments gives me a clear idea，my English is poor  and i will improve this.

Comment: @小丑王 : am glad my comments clarified ur doubt. please consider accepting the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`, and `minimumLineSpacing` is property of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` not `UICollectionViewLayout`.
if your `CustomCollectionViewLayout` is subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` not `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, set `minimumLineSpacing` will crash

Comment: the result is that UICollectionViewLayout the property of UICollectionView is UICollectionViewFlowLayout type ,and it inheritance UICollectionViewLayout